# Troubles getting gRPC and REST together in Dart

Tags: rest, dart, grpc

I have a server and multiple clients (units) which communicate via gRPC. I'm currently trying just one server, one client. The server also accepts calls from user application via REST. So the flow is like this: user app (REST) <-> server (gRPC) <-> unit (do additional REST calls and then report back). In the example I'm trying to keep the code structure as close to the real project as I can. I'm having troubles getting connected the REST API controller with the gRPC.

When I receive REST call on the server, I managed to create `StreamController` with which I send the gRPC request to the client unit. The unit will do some processing and additional REST calls and sends the result back. And here's the problem - how can I read in the REST controller in function `_setPreset` from the gRPC which is processed in the loop in function `unitBus` in separate file? Also how can I (a)wait in the REST controller for the whole call to finish and then send back the REST answer to the user app?
Prints in terminal on the server side after REST call are these:

```
unit bus processing await
unitSubscribeReq: {
  unitId: IUZTR
  configId: asdf
  config: somethingWithConfiguration
}

return rest
unit bus processing await
```

On the server are missing prints from the gRPC loop, these are shown when I call the REST again...
And on the client is this:

```
Got message unitSubscribeRes: {
  data: ok
}

Got message init: {
  config: message
}

VideoCore is offline
else
```

I think this has something to do with async/await but I don't know where. Also I tried to solve the gRPC thing with another `StreamController` but I was stuck on how to connect the whole thing. I'm fairly experienced with REST but the whole gRPC is brand new to me. I would be grateful for at least some pointers where I should look or what to read, I haven't find anything on this particular case. Also as per guidelines I have all the needed code as part of the question but for the sake of convenience (so you don't have to setup whole dart project from scratch) I put it on my github here: https://github.com/Liniik/dart_grpc_rest Thank you for your time

Here's the protofile for gRPC:

```protobuf
syntax = "proto3";

package managing_server;

// Interface exported by the server.
service ManagingServer {
  rpc UnitBus(stream UnitMessage) returns (stream ManagingServerMessage) {}
}

// ---- MESSAGES FROM Managing Server TO Units ---- //
message ManagingServerMessage {
  oneof payload {
    UnitSubscribeRes unit_subscribe_res = 1;
    Init init = 2;
  }
}

message UnitSubscribeRes {
  string data = 1;
}

message Init {
  string config = 1;
}

// ---- MESSAGES / RESPONSES FROM Units TO Managing Server ---- //
message UnitMessage {
  oneof payload {
    UnitSubscribeReq unit_subscribe_req = 1;
    InitSuccess init_success = 2;
    InitError init_error = 3;
  }
}

message UnitSubscribeReq {
  string unit_id = 1;
  string config_id = 2;
  string config = 3;
}

message InitSuccess {}

message InitError {
  string reason = 1;
}
```

Here are server files:

- `bin/server.dart`

```dart
import 'package:grpc/grpc.dart';
import 'package:server/rest_controller.dart';
import 'package:server/server.dart';

void main() async {
  final grpcService = ManagingServerService();
  final restController = RestController();
  restController.loadData(grpcService);
  final gRPCServer = Server.create(services: [grpcService]);
  await gRPCServer.serve(port: 8080);
}
```

- `lib/rest_controller.dart`

```dart
import 'package:server/generated/server.pbgrpc.dart';
import 'package:server/server.dart';
import 'package:shelf_plus/shelf_plus.dart';

class RestController {
  late ManagingServerService grpcService;

  static final RestController _restController = RestController._internal();

  factory RestController() {
    return _restController;
  }

  RestController._internal();

  void createRest() {
    shelfRun(
      init,
      defaultBindPort: 5400,
      defaultBindAddress: 'localhost',
    );
  }

  void loadData(ManagingServerService grpcService) {
    this.grpcService = grpcService;
    _restController.createRest();
  }

  Handler init() {
    var app = Router().plus;
    _initRestPresets(app);
    return app;
  }

  void _initRestPresets(var app) {
    _setPreset(app);
  }

  Future<void> _setPreset(var app) async {
    app.post('/set-preset', (Request request) async {
      RestController().grpcService.ctrl_rest.add(ManagingServerMessage(init: Init(config: "message")));
      print("return rest");
      return Response(204);
    });
  }
}
```

- `lib/server.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:grpc/grpc.dart';
import 'package:server/generated/server.pbgrpc.dart';

class ManagingServerService extends ManagingServerServiceBase {
  StreamController<ManagingServerMessage> ctrl_rest = StreamController();

  @override
  Stream<ManagingServerMessage> unitBus(ServiceCall call, Stream<UnitMessage> request) async* {
    await for (var message in request) {
      print("unit bus processing await");
      print(message);
      switch (message.whichPayload()) {
        case UnitMessage_Payload.unitSubscribeReq:
          yield ManagingServerMessage(unitSubscribeRes: UnitSubscribeRes(data: "ok"));
          break;
        case UnitMessage_Payload.initSuccess:
          print("mng srvr init success");
          break;
        case UnitMessage_Payload.initError:
          print("mng srvr init error");
          print(message.whichPayload());
          break;
        default:
      }
      yield await ctrl_rest.stream.first;
      ctrl_rest = StreamController();
    }
  }
}
```

And here are client files:

- `bin/client.dart`

```dart
import 'package:client/unit_interface.dart';

void main() {
  var client = UnitInterfaceClient();
  client.main();
}
```

- `lib/unit_interface.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:client/video_controller.dart';
import 'package:client/generated/server.pbgrpc.dart';
import 'package:grpc/grpc.dart';

class UnitInterfaceClient {
  late ManagingServerClient stub;
  VideoCoreController videoControls = VideoCoreController();
  final _channel = ClientChannel('127.0.0.1', port: 8080, options: const ChannelOptions(credentials: ChannelCredentials.insecure()));

  Future<void> main() async {
    stub = ManagingServerClient(
      _channel,
    );

    try {
      await runUnitBus();
    } catch (e) {
      print('Caught error: $e');
    }
  }

  Future<void> runUnitBus() async {
    StreamController<UnitMessage> controller = StreamController();

    var msg = UnitSubscribeReq()
      ..unitId = "IUZTR"
      ..configId = "asdf"
      ..config = "somethingWithConfiguration";
    controller.add(UnitMessage(unitSubscribeReq: msg));

    Stream<UnitMessage> subMsg() async* {
      await for (var res in controller.stream) {
        yield res;
      }
    }

    final call = stub.unitBus(subMsg());
    await for (var res in call) {
      UnitMessage message = UnitMessage();
      print('Got message $res');
      switch (res.whichPayload()) {
        case ManagingServerMessage_Payload.unitSubscribeRes:
          break;
        case ManagingServerMessage_Payload.init:
          String? res = await videoControls.init();
          if (res == null) {
            message.initSuccess = InitSuccess();
          } else {
            print("else");
            message.initError = InitError(reason: res);
          }
          break;
        default:
      }
      controller.add(message);
      ProcessSignal.sigint.watch().listen((signal) async {
        print("caught sigint, closing connection...");
        await _channel.shutdown();
        print("connection closed");
        exit(0);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

- `lib/video_controller.dart`

```dart
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class VideoCoreController {
  /// Sends init message to video backend with [settings] and processes response.
  Future<String?> init([String? settings]) async {
    try {
      await http.get(Uri.parse("http://localhost:8090/"));
      return null;
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      print("VideoCore is offline");
      return e.message;
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      print(e);
      return e.toString();
    }
  }
}
```